# Using a JavaScript file to inject HTML into a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently decided that I want an icon to follow the mouse on my web site. So I added the following to a JavaScript file that every page on my site uses

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mouseFollowerHTML = "<img class='mouse-follower' src='/images/space_needle_icon.png' alt='space needle'/>";
    $('.maincontent').append(mouseFollowerHTML);    
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.mouse-follower').offset({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY + 20
    });
});
```

with the intention that it would inject an image into the `maincontent` element (which is on every page) and then have the image follow the mouse. But it's not working. I've tried adding an alert to the `$(document).ready(...)` function, but nothing happened.

Please correct me in the error(s) of my ways.

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your scripts?

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make an image follow mouse pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143806/make-an-image-follow-mouse-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

Check that you connected jQuery to the  of the page:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

And check out this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/sipaxaqipo/1/edit?html,js,console,output (it works fully with your code), so your code is correct. Mistake is somewhere in another part of site, hope you just forgot to connect jQuery.