# making javascript game Follow the line

Tags: javascript

my goal is to make a simple follow-the-line type of game in Javascript. I know nothing of javascript, but I know programming (Java mainly).

In this game, user has to follow a drawn line with his/her mouse pointer. There is start and end point of line, naturally.

So far I found this code: [Make an image follow mouse pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143806/make-an-image-follow-mouse-pointer), but now I'm struggling with checking when mouse coordinates are not inside of line.

I can use any library, so if there are some easy js libraries for games, please recommend them to me.

So, to repeat the question: how do I check if mouse cursor is inside of line (pipe)? If you have any additional advice, please post it.

Comment: You should at least post some code - what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to approach this problem, so I have nothing, except that code from the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to look at this problem. Arguably the easiest would be to create the "pipes" using SVG paths, and then detecting if the mouse was hovering over these lines.

```
<svg>
   <path ...>
</svg>
```

```
$("svg path").hover(function () {
   // I'm inside the line!
}, function () {
   // I left the line!
});
```

This uses a library called jQuery by the way, which I'm going to assume you're using based on your image follow example.

Comment: I know nothing of jQuery (except that it's made to make javascript easier), but I will try using SVG paths, as you recommend. Thank for the answer.