# Make an text follow mouse pointer when hovered over an image link

Tags: javascript, html, css, mediawiki, wikitext

I want to make the text follow the mouse pointer when hovered over an image(Image link) in fandom.
Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8tVd.png) .
Source : [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Deepslate)

Answer (score 0):

It's called a tooltip. The simple solution is to place an attribute `title="Text of tooltip"` on an element. That will produce a generic tooltip depending on the browser/OS.

If you need more control over the design or content, then try googling "tooltop css" or "tooltip javascript".

Comment: I know that but I want like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143806/make-an-image-follow-mouse-pointer/19163828#19163828).And instead of the yellow background I want an image , How can I do that ?

Comment: @ABCXYZ1234 That is a completely different question. Change the styles of `#divtoshow`. However that code it really old and really bad. It only allows a single tooltip on the whole page.